# create users base on other a certain user

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, user-controls

I want to create a django project like stock management systems for multiple companies, but I want the staff of a specific company can only have access their company profile and stocks. case study like multi school management system, if a school register, their staffs can have full access to their school app.

I tried a OneToMany relationship but I don't Know how to do the Auth and restrict the users to only there domain.

Comment: Can you share what you tried, likely this makes it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: It kind of sounds like what you need is a multi-tenant system. There are a number of packages for this: https://djangopackages.org/search/?q=tenant